# IdentityServer Asp.net client force logout on timeout

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have a problem regarding timeouts and Identityserver. Currently I have a web forms client that is authorised through Identityserver, which issues a cookie. After 10 minutes of inactivity this cookie expires and the user is directed to the auth endpoint and is automatically re-authorised with identity. Is it possible to bypass this re-auth step and automatically log the user out instead? Failing that, this there another way a user can be forced to the login page of identity. Ideally I would not want other clients that are authorised through the same identity server to have this ten minute timeout rule. 
My current setup is as follows,

Client Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("Cookies");

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            Authority = "IdentityUrl",
            ClientId = "ClientId",
            ClientSecret = "ClientSecret",
            RedirectUri = "RedirectUri",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "scopes",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "PostLogoutRedirectUri",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = context.OwinContext.Authentication
                                                                                 .User.FindFirst(Constants.ResponseTypes.IdToken)?.Value;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                    id.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.ResponseTypes.IdToken, n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(id, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
public partial class _Default : HSTPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Request.IsAuthenticated) Response.Redirect("HomePageUrl");
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = "CallBackUrl"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the identity server configuration

```
var idpAssemblyName = GetAssemblyName<Startup>();
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore(_configuration))
                .AddConfigurationStore(storeOptions => storeOptions.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(idpAssemblyName)))
                .AddOperationalStore(storeOptions => storeOptions.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options => options.MigrationsAssembly(idpAssemblyName)))
                .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Challenge()` in your `RedirectToIdentityProvider` notification:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
{
    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
        context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = context.OwinContext.Authentication
                                                                 .User.FindFirst(Constants.ResponseTypes.IdToken)?.Value;

    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Token)
    {
        n.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when the client cookie has expired we enter `RedirectToIdentityProvider` with a `ProtocolMessage` with type `Authentication` and not `Token`, so the flow remains the same

Comment: Does it work with `Challenge()` there? Or try with `SignOut()`.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. If I remove the conditional and just call `Challenge()` I get the same behaviour. If I call `SignOut()` instead I run into a different problem due to the fact that on first direct to the client we will be trying to sign out a user that is not yet logged in. This means we hit the logout endpoint without a id_token_hint and therefore don't get a post logout redirect populated correctly. Ideally it seems like we want the user to challenge on first direct to the client app, and signout when the cookie expires

Comment: Then try first checking `if (n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply's. However in both cases (on first load and when the client cookie has expired) `IsAuthenticated` is false.

Comment: I'm out of ideas there. Try setting your client in IdentityServer. Don't use refresh token (remove offline_access scope), and set access and identity token lifetimes to the same value.